# How can I invoke hook function after the block is loaded?

Tags: 8, hooks

I have created a view with content types in my Drupal 8 and for this view page I have created a customised filter. The view page is located in sites/mysite/modules/view/config/install

And the customised filter is located in sites/mysite/modules/filter/src/Plugin/Block

The issue for me is that I want to change a title of the filter in hook function in view.module . But it is loaded before the FilterBlock. How can I specify the order of the invoked files?

Answer (score 1):

To change the order of which module's hook will fire first when more than one module implements the same hook you can use [`hook_module_implements_alter()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Extension%21module.api.php/function/hook_module_implements_alter/8.6.x). It was created for exactly this kind of situation.

Answer (score 1):

There is two way to do so :

1. Using this module [modules weight](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Extension%21module.api.php/function/hook_module_implements_alter/8.6.x)
2. Using [hook_module_implements_alter](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Extension%21module.api.php/function/hook_module_implements_alter/8.6.x)